# Search user after age. How to calculate the correct determined age?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to search user after their age:

```
(Age input saved in variables $a1 - $a2)
Age: □ - □ 
     -Search button-
```

If I select Age: 20-50 i want all users between 20-50 years old to be listed.
If i select Age: x-30 i want all user up to 30 years old to be listed.

In the db i save the users birthdays with this format: 2013-03-03.

To calculate the users age and echo the age on the webpage I do this:

```
<?php 

$ag=$row['age'];
$diff=time()-strtotime($ag);
$age=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ag));

echo floor($diff/60/60/24/365.25); 
?>
```

**How do i make a Select query where age > $a1 and < $a2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calculating the age from the returned date you should calculate the date from the desired age

```
$mindate = is_numeric($a2)? date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-$a2 year')) : null;
$maxdate = is_numeric($a1)? date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-$a1 year')) : null;
$query = "SELECT * FROM whatevertable WHERE ";
if(!is_null($mindate))
   $query .= "datecolumn > '$mindate'";
if(!is_null($maxdate)){
   if(!is_null($mindate)
      $query .= " AND ";
   $query .= "datecolumn < $maxdate";
}
```

Validation and query polishing are left as exercise.

Comment: I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' at 
$query.= " AND ";
and
$query.= "'$age' < $maxdate";

Comment: $mindate = is_numeric($a2)? date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-$a2 year')) : null;
$maxdate = is_numeric($a1)? date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-$a1 year')) : null;
$query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE c='$c'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$age= $row['age'];
if(!is_null($mindate))
   $query.= "'$age' > '$mindate'";
if(!is_null($maxdate)){
   if(!is_null($mindate)
      $query.= " AND ";
   $query.= "'$age' < $maxdate";
}

Comment: @anon I defined $query as a string, you defined it as the result of mysqly_query...